# Restrict write of specific char on specific place c#

Tags: c#, winforms, char

I made a textbox for user input which receives text and converts it to double. I don't want to allow the user to crash my program, but also I want to know how can I do that instead of try catch. Input is positive or negative double.

For now I got this:

```
private void txtForceX_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char ch = e.KeyChar;

    if (ch == 44 && txtForceX.Text.IndexOf(',') != -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    if (ch == 45 && txtForceX.Text.IndexOf ('-') != -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    if (!char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 44 && ch != 45)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

As you can see restrictions are only 1 minus(-) and only 1 decimal separator(,) available.
How to restrict minus(-) to be written only on first place?
For example:

- -140,3  is ok
- 41-,02  is not ok (crashes program) --> this needs to be set up

Comment: Do you definitely need to actually prevent the invalid value from being typed, or just accepted? I find it's usually simpler to validate the value afterwards - which you can do without a try/catch block using `TryParse`.

Comment: well, both.. i'd like to prevent invalid value from being typed more.. like if you press (-) as first char then it would be ok, but when you press it after, then i don't want anything to happen... don't want to alow the user to write (-) on any other place instead of first

Comment: Maybe you take a look in this [implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) provided by Microsoft.

Comment: @dodoria1992: Personally (as a user) I'd rather use something that just allowed me to type, but indicated an invalid value as I go along, so I can fix it. Maybe after typing the "-" in the wrong place, the user will remove the rest. There are all kinds of situations where it's hard to spot invalid input on a keypress-by-keypress basis, such as  copy and paste. If I copy "--" onto the clipboard and then paste it into your textbox, what would you expect to happen?

Comment: hmmm... you got a good point there, but I don't think someone would copy paste in it since the texbox recieve only 10 chars.. and that are small numbers (up to 1000 max)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just use [double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to try to convert the typed value to a number. Something like this should work (not tested):

```
private void txtForceX_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   double value;
   if(!double.TryParse(txtForceX.Text, out value)
       e.Handled = true;
}
```

**EDIT:** As Jon points out in the comments, this will not work as expected and the safest thing to do is probably to let the user type anything, then validate the input externally, e.g. not allowing the user to save the data if the input is invalid:

```
private void txtForceX_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   double value;
   var isValid = double.TryParse(txtForceX.Text, out value);
   btnSave.Enabled = isValid;
}
```

Complement/replace this with an error message, a visual indication of the value being invalid, or whatever better suits your application.

Comment: That stops "intermediate" invalid input though, e.g. "-" as the start of writing "-10". I think it would be better to just validate the value and show the validity state, not accepting it if it's not valid - but allowing the user to *type* anything.

Comment: since this is in KeyPress event, this code stop me from typing anything

Comment: this is working, sort of... but when i type for example -1, it does not enable button, only when i put -11 (two chars after minus) ... when textbox is empty, button is enabled, but when i click on a number 5 (with or without minus), it gets disabled, becouse it's not double

Answer (score 0):

You said - How to restrict minus(-) to be written only on first place?

This way you can do that:-

```
if (ch == 45 && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```